# validation oldPassword with userPassword Symfony2

Tags: validation, symfony, passwords, getter

I have the next code that is now working fine but Im trying to validate the oldPassword, but ever appear the error message that it dont match.

```
Aspersoft\DirectorioBundle\Entity\User:
properties:
    password:
        - NotBlank: { groups: [change_password] }
        - Length: { min: 3, max: 20, minMessage: "La cotraseña debe de contener minimo {{ limit }} caracteres de longitud.", maxMessage: "La cotraseña debe de contener maximo {{ limit }} caracteres de longitud.", groups: [change_password]}
    oldPassword:
        - Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Validator\Constraints\UserPassword:
            groups: [change_password]
```

and in my entity class:

```
/**
 * User
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="user", indexes={@ORM\Index(name="user_index_1", columns={"id_municipality"})})
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Aspersoft\DirectorioBundle\Entity\UserRepository")
 */
class User implements AdvancedUserInterface, \Serializable {

    public $oldPassword;

// more properties, getters and setters...
```

somebody knows what can be the problem? and how I would create the property OldPassword or maybe if it would be serialized in entity, In the symfony page there is poor information about Constraint UserPassword.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution.
I needed create the form from a Type to work properly with validation class.